# How to get all colums + custom ones in Azure App Insights (KQL)

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql

I have a simple query like below;

```
union isfuzzy=true
    availabilityResults,
    requests,
    exceptions,
    pageViews,
    traces,
    customEvents,
    dependencies
| order by timestamp desc
| take 100
```

This returns all available columns, which is fine. Then when I use following;

```
union isfuzzy=true
    availabilityResults,
    requests,
    exceptions,
    pageViews,
    traces,
    customEvents,
    dependencies
| order by timestamp desc
| take 100
| project customDimensions.ApplicationName
```

This only returns `ApplicationName` column, this is also fine.

But what I want it to get additional column on top of existing ones, similar to:

```
union isfuzzy=true
    availabilityResults,
    requests,
    exceptions,
    pageViews,
    traces,
    customEvents,
    dependencies
| order by timestamp desc
| take 100
| project *, customDimensions.ApplicationName
```

But `*` wildcard does not work here. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the result table to include *all* existing columns, and extend another calculated column in addition to those.

If that's correct, you can use the [`extend` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extendoperator).

e.g.:

```
union isfuzzy=true
    availabilityResults,
    requests,
    exceptions,
    pageViews,
    traces,
    customEvents,
    dependencies
| top 100 by timestamp desc
| extend ApplicationName = customDimensions.ApplicationName
```